# linear gradient background property not working when navigating screens with next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I ran into something weird with next js.  My background linear gradients are not loading when I switch pages.

My link is

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href='/register'>
   <a> click me </a>
</Link>
```

and I have a div with

```
style={{
   background: 'linear-gradient(153.68deg, #17191D 0%, #0C152C 45.82%);',
}}
```

When I click the link the linear gradient is not loading and the background is plain white.  When I refresh the page the linear gradient loads and it works.

*Also : I'm using tailwind.  If I add

```
className='bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500'
```

to my div instead of using the style background property I can see a linear gradient when navigating with the link.

Any help your be greatly appreciated!  I want to be able to use the style background property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tailwind @layer utility` for this like below.

1. Just go to globals.css and add this

   ```
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;


   @layer{
    .backy  {
      background-image: linear-gradient(153.68deg, #17191D 0%, #0C152C
     45.82%);
     }
    }
   ```

And then use it like this

```
<div class="h-screen w-screen p-10 text-white backy" >Hello</div>
```